# Sharepoint 2013: Custom masterpage doesn't appear on the list in masterpage settings

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm new to Sharepoint so maybe I'm missing something simple. I created an additional masterpage by copying "seattle" and modifying some things in the html file. The .master file was created automatically. Then, I created a new "composed look" that included my new masterpage, and applied it.

However, when I go to site settings and then to masterpage settings (the place where I can pick if a site should inherit a masterpage or have its own), the only masterpages available are still just the two default ones, "oslo" and "seattle". What should I do to make my custom masterpage appear there? And another problem, maybe it's related, is that when I create a subsite, the subsite doesn't get my custom masterpage, only "oslo" and "seattle". When I visit the subsite's master page list in Sharepoint Designer, it only contains "minimal.master", "oslo.master", "seattle.master", and "v4.master", but my own custom masterpage wasn't copied to the subsite. :( The subsite also doesn't have my own custom "composed look", only the default ones.

Comment: Did you publish your new master page (created the major version)? Btw, you only need to publish .html file... the .master file will be automatically published.

Comment: I published it now and it's working, thank you very much! There was no indication anywhere that it was unpublished.